# Amcharts - Labelbullet is getting cutoff

Tags: max, bar-chart, amcharts, truncate, bullet

[image]

```
> `<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 230px;"></div>
> 
> am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
> 
> Create chart instance
> var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
> 
> Add data
> chart.data = [{
>   "category": "Research",
>   "value": 116.875
> }, {
>   "category": "Marketing",
>   "value": 115
> }, {
>   "category": "Distribution",
>   "value": 96.33333
> }];
> 
> var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
> categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
> categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
> 
> var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
> valueAxis.max = 120;
> valueAxis.min = 0;
> var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
> series.dataFields.valueX = "value";
> series.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
> 
> var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
> valueLabel.label.text = "{value}";
> valueLabel.label.fontSize = 20;
> valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";`
```

Above is my code. Here the labelbullet 116.875 value is getting cutoff as shown in the image but it should not.

Tried Wrap,truncate, setting maxwidh, minwidth and all but nothing worked out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.